# Python console_scripts with multi level module

Tags: python, setuptools

I have the following code in setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='raas',
    version='0.1',
    description='Program to test console_scripts\'s\n.',
    packages=['raas'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['raas = raas.cli.entry:main',
                            'raas1 = raas.test:main']
    },
    zip_safe=True,
)
```

The package structure is

```
$ --> ls -lR
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  6 noorul  wheel  192 Mar 22 01:37 raas
-rw-r--r--  1 noorul  wheel  349 Mar 22 01:37 setup.py

./raas:
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 noorul  wheel    0 Mar 22 01:28 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--  1 noorul  wheel  103 Mar 22 01:32 __init__.pyc
drwxr-xr-x  6 noorul  wheel  192 Mar 22 01:32 cli
-rw-r--r--  1 noorul  wheel   29 Mar 22 01:37 test.py

./raas/cli:
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 noorul  wheel    0 Mar 22 01:28 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--  1 noorul  wheel  107 Mar 22 01:32 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 noorul  wheel   37 Mar 22 01:29 entry.py
-rw-r--r--  1 noorul  wheel  234 Mar 22 01:32 entry.pyc
```

Contents of the entry.py and test.py are

```
$ --> cat raas/cli/entry.py
def main():
    print "Hellow world"

$ --> cat raas/test.py
def main():
    print "Test"
```

But after installing the package using setup.py install in a virtual env. I could only run raas1 and not raas

```
$ --> ./venv/bin/raas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./venv/bin/raas", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('raas==0.1', 'console_scripts', 'raas')()
  File "/private/tmp/raas/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 480, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/private/tmp/raas/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2693, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/private/tmp/raas/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2324, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/private/tmp/raas/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2330, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named cli.entry

$ --> ./venv/bin/raas1
Test
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problem

What you are missing lies in the line

```
packages=['raas'],
```

You might think that this will include `raas` with all its subpackages, but it doesn't! `packages=['raas']` will include only `raas/__init__.py` and every python module in `raas` directory - in your case the `test.py`. This is why `raas1` command works.

However, none of the subpackages of `raas` will be included, so the `raas.cli` subpackage won't be installed. You should be able to verify it is missing by listing the installed files with `pip` (if you have installed the package with it):

```
$ pip show -f raas
Name: raas
Version: ...
...
Files:
  ...
  raas/__init__.py
  raas/test.py
```

You should see neither `raas/cli/__init__.py` nor `raas/cli/entry.py` in the files list.

#### Solution

The obvious solution is to include `raas.cli` to the packages list:

```
packages=['raas', 'raas.cli'],
```

However, it's pretty clumsy to maintain: when adding new package or renaming an existing one, you have to include the changes in the packages list in `setup.py` or they will not be included in the distribution. Since you are already using `setuptools`, it offers a much better solution:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

The function `find_packages()` will perform a recursive scan of the current directory, looking for python packages, and generate a list of qualified package names that will be included in the distribution. [Read its doc for more details.](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages)

Comment: packages=['raas', 'raas.cli'], worked but find_packages did not.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it should be `find_packages()`. Sorry, wrote the answer yesterday without actually testing the code! I will update the answer now.